Writing the objective function of the mathematical model of an article in GAMS code
I have an exercise where I need to reproduce the mathematical model of an article in GAMS.
So I've written the beginning of the code with all the sets and parameters but I don't know how to write the objective function. Can someone help me ?
Here is my code : https://i.sstatic.net/pc2QMGfg.png, https://i.sstatic.net/82iCmE6T.png, https://i.sstatic.net/6HO6bmUB.png, https://i.sstatic.net/EggzOzZP.png, https://i.sstatic.net/DdT3f9c4.png
And here is the article model: Sets and Indices: https://i.sstatic.net/Z4fKGALm.png, Parameters: https://i.sstatic.net/fo1dfx6t.png, Decision Variables: https://i.sstatic.net/MBqBwjjp.png, Objective Function: https://i.sstatic.net/3AVcFglD.png
I didn't put the constraints, for now I'm only trying to write the objective function without errors.
Thank you!
